# SharePoint Framework Extension Deployment Challenges

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, custom-action, listviewcommandset

I am quite new to SharePoint and want to know if I can create a custom variable(property) in SharePoint Online (may be at site level and Tenant level) and use it in SPFx.

I had a requirement to create a custom action in SharePoint Online for which I used SPFx ListView Command Set.

I really liked the ease of creating one and deploying it on my office cdn.

However now I need to make SPFx generic enough so that my customers can deploy the sppkg on their sites without much modification.

The problem is that some of the properties that I am using need to be configurable by the site admin.

How can I make this SPFx generic so that the client side admin does not need to change the properties/configuration , package -solution it and deploy it.

A quick answer will be very helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [tenant properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/tenant-properties) can be configured by SharePoint Online Management Shell and read by rest api(`GET _api/web/GetStorageEntity('key')`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. I am definitely going to try it..